# Automatically login to webpage with swift 4

Tags: swift, authentication, wkwebview

I have a WkWebView in my app which takes users to a third party webpage where they have to login to access relevant information. All users of the app use the same pre-shared login details (app is managed by enterprise distribution to a small number of people).

I want the app to automatically fill username and password details and then submit all without user input. I've been looking at lots of posts on here and trying to make a post request with webViewDidFinishLoad, but not had luck so far. Most information is around storing and recalling user details rather than a pre-shared username and password.

Any help to point in the right direction would be great.

Current code just to load the website is:

import UIKit
import WebKit

```
class TreliskeWeatherViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let treliskeWeather = URL(string: " ")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: treliskeWeather!)
        webView.load(myRequest)

    }
}
    extension TreliskeWeatherViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print("Finished navigating to url")

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can evaluate the javascript file once the webview is finished loading. I am using timeout and interval logic in javascript just to make sure elements exist. I am only checking sign in button here but you can check all the three if you want.

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    guard let jsFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "injectCredentials", withExtension: "js") else {
        return
    }

    do {
        let injectJS = try String(contentsOf: jsFile)
        let formatted = String(format: injectJS, "username", "password")
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(formatted) { (value, error) in
          //
        }
    } catch {
        //
    }
}
```

injectCredentials.js

```
var timeoutSeconds = 30;

var username = "%@";
var password = "%@";

var checkLogin = setInterval(checkLoginFields, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
       clearInterval(checkLogin);
       }, timeoutSeconds * 1000);

function checkLoginFields() {
  var usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');
  var passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');
  var signInButton = document.getElementById("login");
  if (signInButton == null) {
    return;
  }
  usernameInput.value = username;
  passwordInput.value = password;
  signInButton.click();
  clearInterval(checkLogin);
}
```

Comment: Arpit can you contact me I am a bit of a beginner and have need to get past a logging screen also. than you so much. Appreciated. Regards Mike